# ASP.net HTTP request with patch method

Tags: apex, rest-api, api, c#, .net

Example for creating Account

```
curl https://na1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/customExtIdField__c/11999 -H "Authorization: Bearer token" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @newrecord.json -X PATCH
```

Example request body newrecord.json file

```
{
"Name" : "Express Logistics and Transport"
}
```

My ASP.net code :

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
     client.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token.access_token);
     client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
     NameValueCollection reqparm = new NameValueCollection();
     reqparm.Add("Name", "This Is Test Data");
     byte[] responsebytes = client.UploadValues(token.instance_url + "/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/customExtIdField__c/11999", "PATCH", reqparm);
     string responsebody = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responsebytes);
}
```

Above code is not working. Getting Error (405) Method Not Allowed. I don't know how to use Patch Method.